# Core Data vs. Database fundamental difference?

Tags: database, core-data

Can someone explain to me what the fundamental difference is between Core Data (apparently, a "data store") and a database like SQLite or MySQL?

I am working on writing an iPhone app, and needed a table of static data to display. I thought core data would be a good choice for this, so I got everything set up and functioning as far as the database (i'm sorry - data STORE) went, and then went to try to import my data (it was in an excel file which I exported to CSV). I was thinking it should be a straight forward process like I have done in SQLite and other databases many times, but as it turned out after much research, the only "official" way to do this was to write a parser specifically for my data.

When I asked about this on the Apple Developer forums, the response I got was basically "What kind of idiot are you to think that you could possibly import data directly without having to write code to do it? Core data isn't a database- it's a data STORE!!" For the life of me, though, I can't see the distinction. In every way I have looked at it, core data behaves EXACTLY like a database, with a fancy way of accessing it and enough abstraction that it can use a variety of file formats for actually storing the data. In fact, I was eventually able to import my data using a simple SQLite .import command, so I really don't understand why the concept was so foreign to the responders to my original question.

So what am I missing here? What is so fundamentally different about a data store from a database that makes the concept of simple data importing completely alien to those who know the technology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Core Data is not simply a means of persisting/storing data to and from disk as is SQL. Core Data's true function is to provide the complete model layer for the Model-View-Controller app design that the Apple API uses. As such Core Data is primarily an object-graph manager with persistence options tack onto the side.

An object-graph is a collection of live objects in memory. In Core Data, these are the managed objects. They are called "managed" objects because the managed object context observes the objects constantly making sure they are in the states and relationships that the data model says they should be in.

Core Data does provide persistence option but exactly what that option is for any particular implementation is largely hidden. You can even use the same data model and managed objects with different persistence methods, sometime in the same app.

The key difference with SQL is that SQL writes the actual data to disk whereas Core Data serializes live objects. When you look at a sqlite store in Core Data you are looking at objects that have been taken apart and "freeze dried". Obviously, "freeze drying" objects requires a rather specific data format in the sqlite store so the Core Data store uses its own custom schema that is largely the same regardless of details of the store.

That is why you can't just swap in any old SQL file and expect Core Data to import it. The SQL file is rows, tables and columns of data and not a specialized tables, columns and rows use to reconstitute freeze dried objects.

Since Core Data is first and foremost an object-graph manager, the only supported and reliable means of importing data is to create the object-graph. In the case of an SQL file, that means reading the SQL data using the SQL api and then generating managed objects from that data and then saving them to a persistent store.

That part is more work but you save time integrating the data into the rest of the app, upgrading the data and gains in reliability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary definition gives me:
Databases are data stores, but a data store isn't always a database.

The feature you expected isn't available in some databases either (but most are).

A data store can for example store non-relational data.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is not a data store, a data store is one part of Core Data. Core Data is closer related to an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) tool. Core Data actually has the option of using SQLite for it's datastore, but you can also choose XML files, proprietary format, or write your own datastore.

Not sure how you were able to import your data with a SQL import, shouldn't be compatible with Core Data since Core Data creates a proprietary SQL database schema that contains a ton of metadata.

Comment: Simple: while the schema is proprietary, there's nothing terribly unusual about it. Once you have let the Core Data stack create the database, it is obvious which table and columns hold the actual data, and completely straightforward to do a .import FILE TABLE. You just have to massage your data a (small) bit to match the schema (column orders and the like). The other data doesn't matter when importing.

Answer (score 0):

They should have just pointed you at the [Wikipedia article on Core Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data).

According to that article, "It allows data organised by the relational entity-attribute model to be serialised into XML, binary, or SQLite stores. The data can be manipulated using higher level objects representing entities and their relationships. Core Data manages the serialised version, providing object lifecycle and object graph management, including persistence. Core Data interfaces directly with SQLite, insulating the developer from the underlying SQL."

I guess it's the fact that "Core Data manages the serialised version" that means you can't import data directly. That is, you probably can't import data directly into SQLite in such a way that Core Data can manage it, although you probably *can* import data directly into SQLite in *some* way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to think of Core Data as an "object store" and a database as a "data store". Core Data is good when you have a variety of types of object, with relationships to each other. The familiar example is a company with employees, who have bosses and reports, belong to departments, are assigned to clients, projects, etc., have schedules, go to meetings. Employees can get reassigned, etc. Even the types of relationships defined vary from time to time. That's a more heavyweight process even with Core Data, but Core Data makes it more easy than with a raw database.

If you just have "data", and not "objects", it's easier to use a database. For example if you just have a table of the elements with atomic weights, etc., you might want to just use a database.

For your application it sounds like you just have one table. It will be easy to just use SQLite, which is available, so use it if it's more convenient.

On the other hand, iOS SDK has some pre-built features that interact with Core Data. If you use SQLite you don't get those. So you might avoid custom code to import your data but have to write custom code to display your data. Tough luck. When creating software sometimes you have to write code. Weird, I know.