# Primary key position in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite, core-data

In CoreData , I learnt that ,

Core Data makes its own primary key - you don't have to add one. You can retrieve it with

`NSManagedObjectID *moID = [managedObject objectID];`

Now My question is , suppose I have 3 data and if I delete something from say primary key postion 1 and I want to add some new data , on which position it will add ? will that position is primarykey 4 ? and If I want to add this new data at position - primary key 1 How should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The managed object id is not the primary key of your data - it's a unique reference that Core Data uses internally and is used in our applications to fetch an object in different contexts by using that ID.

From your question it seems that you are trying to add an object in a specific location. That is not what the objectID is for. If you want to keep things in a specific order, then you need to add a attribute that you use for sorting, or use an ordered relationship which will take care of this for you.

Comment: so in the attribute how can I make some attribute incremental than how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The managed object ID is used to uniquely identity managed objects across multiple managed object contexts. It cannot be used to keep objects in a certain order.

To keep the managed objects in a well-defined order, you have to add your own key attribute to
the entity, and use that in the sort descriptor of the fetch request.

Comment: okay , if I want to use pk in coredata , I have to add my own attribute for that , there is no way I can use the pk generated by core data .. right ? because I can see some primary keys in sql db genrated by coredata in command line tool .

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard: You are right. The Core Data framework does not give you access to the primary key used for the SQLite store.

Comment: so what is core data actually ?? a wrapper that do operations on the sqlite created by apple ? and there is no way I can do such operations which includes primary key , foreign key  then I have to use my own attribute for that ?

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard: Core Data is a "object graph manager with lifecycle, searching and persistence features", and not a database. See http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373281/core-data-vs-database-fundamental-difference. - You don't need foreign keys with Core Data, you define "relationships" instead.

Comment: so in the attribute how can I make some attribute incremental than how can I do it ?

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard: There is no built-in method. You have to keep track of the largest key (or execute a fetch request to determine the largest used key), then increment and assign it to your objects.