# How to suppress warning of no inverse relationship?

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode8

I want to suppress warnings of:

> Entity.detail should have an inverse

and

> Entity.detail does not have an inverse; this is an advanced setting
>   (no object can be in multiple destinations for a specific
>   relationship)

I have tried to change all value of following to Yes, but doesn't work:
[image]

I am using XCode 8.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: Sorry, I should edit it on Project's Build Settings, not Target's Build Settings..

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the very unusual (and very tricky to get correct) situation that you're in that requires you to not have an inverse relationship, and what you've done to address the many consistency problems that configuration creates.

Comment: @RobNapier I need to store CLLocationCoordinate2D. An entity Vehicle can have a location as  CLLocationCoordinate2D  and an entity VehicleRoute can have array of CLLocationCoordinate2D as its path. Why would I ever need inverse of these?

Comment: @BangOperator In order to maintain database integrity when using a database backend. Core Data relies on reverse relationships in order to manage deletions correctly. Without them, you have to manage deletions by hand, and if not very careful, you can corrupt the backing database. Note that in my experience, storing very large numbers of coordinates doesn't really map well to a persistent object graph. It's often looks more like a database problem, and you may do much better using a database rather than Core Data (which is a persistent object graph, not a database) for that piece.

Comment: A couple of links that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375798/97337 https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html

Answer (score 3):

For anybody wondering in the future, [@Rendy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1352755/rendy) was right in his first comment on the question. The solution is to go to the project build settings (click on your project name in the navigation side bar as shown below) and then change the setting for "**Suppress momc warnings on missing inverse relationships**" to "**Yes**" (as shown below)
[image: How to get to project build settings]
[image: The setting to change]

Comment: Thanks so much, this warning is not true in 99% of cases and was so annoying!

Answer (score -1):

You don't suppress it-- you **fix** it, by adding an inverse relationship. The compiler is trying to tell you that you're doing something wrong. The right response is to fix the thing you're doing wrong.

Comment: I need to store CLLocationCoordinate2D. An entity Vehicle can have a location as CLLocationCoordinate2D and an entity VehicleRoute can have array of CLLocationCoordinate2D as its path. Why would I ever need inverse of these? How can I fix this?

Comment: You would add an inverse relationship because Core Data uses them to maintain data integrity. Based on your description you might be better off saving location data as attributes rather than as a separate entity, which would not require a relationship.

Comment: "better off saving location data as attributes", yes I can do that for "Vehicle". So "Vehicle" can now have two new attributes "lat" and "long". But how do I model this for "VehicleRoute" entity that has array of "lat" and "long"? I do need a separate entity for this and thus relationships.

Comment: You could use a transformable attribute.

Comment: This is not strictly true. It explicitly says, "this is an advanced setting". This means that it is supported but discouraged (hence it being a warning instead of an error).